# Retrieve devise token as string with NSUserdefault

Tags: xcode, swift3, push-notification

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Convert token to string


    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

    // Print it to console
    print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
    UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token = deviceTokenString
```

Then when I print `UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token` in viewdidloaud in my view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.token)
```

it prints nil!

how can I save the token as a string to send it to my backend ?

```
 struct DefaultsKey
 {

static let Token = "token"


}


class UserDataSingleton
   {
      static let sharedDataContainer = UserDataSingleton()
init() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    self.token = defaults.object(forKey:DefaultsKey.Token) as? String

}
var token : String?{
    didSet {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(token, forKey:DefaultsKey.Token)

    }
}
```

Comment: Show `UserDataSingleton`s implementation. Also set a breakpoint to see if `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called after `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` might be executed sooner than `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. Btw: there is a `string(forKey` method.

Comment: @shallowThought it prints the devise token in the delegate file but in my view controller it's nil. please check my question

Comment: I set it in viewwillappear but it's still nil

Comment: Add print lines to check the timing.

Comment: the lines are printed

Comment: Is `APNs device token...` printed before or after *it prints nil!* ?

Comment: I think devise token is saved as Data! how can I convert it to NSString ? I think it's already converted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145066/discussion-between-leo0019-and-vadian).